# What is the best way to call children method from parent in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

from what i found out you can use two ways, if you need to execute children method from parent.

1. `props` You can use prop and listen for changes of specific one

`export default class SomeClass extends Component {
    ...
    componentDidUpdate(oldProps) {
        if(oldProps.someValue !== this.props.someValue) {
            //prop changed, trigger children method
        }
    }
    ...
}`

2. `ref` You can use reference to children

`export default class SomeClass extends Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.children.execute()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Children ref="children" />
        )
     }
     ...
}`

Is there any other way? I found out first way hard to do, if there are more than few props.I believe second is not good either, because if you change the function once, it must be refactored everywhere.

Comment: Between the two I would say the first option is better. Using `ref` in general is to be avoided. But what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I agree with @Aaron but child components should be "dumb" components. If anything they should call a function that's in the parent. Can you add more clarification on what you're doing?

Comment: @Aaron I'm trying to trigger animation of children component. Children comonent have all data for animation from parent, and parent have button which should trigger reanimating of children data

Comment: @M.Svrcek Given that, I would say `componentWillReceiveProps` is the way to go. Ideally the parent shouldn't know what effect the props will have on the child, it just passes the props and the child handles the way it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: "to call children method from parent in reactjs" can only be done *indirectly*, never *directly*.

You can use a prop to pass from parent to child,
And have a method inside child that executes based on prop, or on prop change.
It looks like your option 1 describes the scenario where you want to execute child method on prop change only.
With "more than a few props" this may seem hard to do, but the benefit is that you manage all the complexity in one place where it belongs: inside the child itself. This makes your code easier to maintain and to debug.

Another way is: inside the child, add a listener to some event, which triggers the child's own method. Event can be a DOM event (such as onChange, or onKeyDown), or a store change if you are using flux.

You can pass a method from parent to child as a prop, to allow the child to call the parent's method. But you cannot pass a method from child to parent, to have the parent call the child's method.

These really are the only clean ways to have an outside trigger for a method inside a react component.

You really should not use refs to directly call the child's method. Not ever. Not from the parent, nor from anywhere else.